# How to check MIME type of a file to get the extension of the file in python

Tags: python-2.7

Code below:

```
import magic
import mimetypes

def get_type(file_name):
    """check mimetype of file

Argument:

    filename: target filename path
"""
if 'from_file' in dir(magic):
    return magic.from_file(file_name, mime=True)
else:
m = magic.open(magic.MAGIC_MIME)
m.load()
file_type = m.file(file_name).split(';')[0]
return mimetypes.guess_extension(file_type, strict=True)
# return file_type


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_type = get_type('1.pdf')
    print file_type
```

Comment: when i am using mimetypes.guess_extension its not giving the proper result

Comment: Can you please post what output you are getting?

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan, its working now if we use guess_all_extensions from mimetypes. But problem in windows system how to check the mime type of a file.

Comment: Any info to get content-type of a a file in windows